# Vue... $ is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm learning Vue at the moment, and I'm now at the point where I want to make a call to my backend and pull data in JSON format. I've followed multiple Vue tutorials online (admittedly they are all from Laracast) and they each say to use $.get to make a get request to the backend. However, I'm getting a `$ is undefined` error. From reading, it seems this may be because $ is a jQuery attribute, but if that's the case, how come these tutorials haven't mentioned anything about importing or setting up jQuery? What would be the Vue-only way of doing a simple get request?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head><title>Tests</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="item in queue">{{ item }}</div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS file:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        queue: [],
        interval: null,
    },
    methods: {
        loadData: function () {
            $.get('localhost:4567/getQueue', function (response) {
                this.queue = response;
            }.bind(this));
        }
    },
    ready: function () {
        this.loadData();

        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
            this.loadData();
        }.bind(this), 3000); 
    },

    beforeDestroy: function(){
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a hastily written tutorial, adding the [jQuery library](http://code.jquery.com/) before or after the Vue library will solve your problems; However, I've found the main [Vue examples / tutorials](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/) good enough to completely learn Vue.

I'd also highly suggest learning the [`.vue` template (Single File Components)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html). As later on it becomes much more valuable to your architecture and speeds up development quite a bit.

If you're interested in more Vue resources [check out this site](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue).